# Multiplication Table print to console

Tags: javascript

So my goal is to print a multiplication table in the console. This snippet of code works, but only until I try to put it into a function.

I've replaced the console.log at the end of the loops with a return (see below) and then it only gives me 3 lines of output. I hope this is clear enough this is my first time posting.

```
  const multiplicationTable = function(maxValue) {



    for (let i = 0; i < 0; i++){
        // This is shown to verify which value is the one on the 
         multiplication table with each line
        //console.log(""+i);
        // then it clears the variable tableLine with each new line
        let tableLine = "";

        for (let j = 1; j <= maxValue; j++) {
            // It will add the results to a string each time
         tableLine += ""+(i*j)+" ";

        }  return tableLine; //and display each line in the console

      } 
    } 



    console.log(multiplicationTable(1));
    console.log(multiplicationTable(5));
    console.log(multiplicationTable(10));

    //1
    //
    //1 2 3 4 5
    //2 4 6 8 10
    //3 6 9 12 15
    //4 8 12 16 20
    //5 10 15 20 25 
    //
    //1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
    //2 4 6 8 10 12 14 16 18 20
    //3 6 9 12 15 18 21 24 27 30
    //4 8 12 16 20 24 28 32 36 40
    //5 10 15 20 25 30 35 40 45 50
    //6 12 18 24 30 36 42 48 54 60
    //7 14 21 28 35 42 49 56 63 70
    //8 16 24 32 40 48 56 64 72 80
    //9 18 27 36 45 54 63 72 81 90
    //10 20 30 40 50 60 70 80 90 100
```

Comment: What do you mean by "This snippet of code works, but only until I try to put it into a function."? The code is already in a function and seems to work fine if it's printing what you show here (although it looks like you need to insert a newline after each row).

Comment: 1 
5 10 15 20 25 
10 20 30 40 50 60 70 80 90 100
is what i get when i run it inside the function. I got the correct output without a function but inside my function i get the above

Comment: const multiplicationTable = function(maxValue)

Comment: You return tableLine, the function will stop after you return, i.e. it will only ever return the first line of each table.. which is what you're seeing.

Comment: Thanks for that, still unclear of what to use if not return to complete the function. Its an assignment so I have to keep the console.log(multiplicationTable(5)) output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `return` inside a function, it will immediately exit the function and will not continue the rest of the processing.

What you will need to do is to have another constant (eg. `table`) to store your `tableLine`. At the end of the processing, you return the `table` value.

I have modified your code and you can see it below for your reference.
You will be able to get the same output as you expect.

```
function multiplicationTable(maxValue) {
  let table = "";

  for (let i = 1; i <= maxValue; i++) {
    let tableLine = "";
    for (let j = 1; j <= maxValue; j++) {
     tableLine += ""+(i*j)+" ";
    }

    tableLine += "\n";
    table += tableLine;
  } 

  return table;
}
```